# UINotification for specific days

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am writing an alarm app. In the app user can select days for setting alarm on that day with time. But I don't know to set UILocalNotification for specific day in a week.

How I know about repeat interval. I know that I must to set

How to calculate how many days will come Friday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to Get an NSDate for a Specific Day of Week and Time from an Existing NSDate](http://danroundhill.com/2011/05/16/how-to-get-an-nsdate-for-a-specific-day-of-week-and-time-from-an-existing-nsdate/) - this article will help you with this problem. You can get NSDate from current Friday with:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
 
NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
 
[nowComponents setWeekday:6];
[nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week]]; // Current week
[nowComponents setHour:8]; // 8a.m.
[nowComponents setMinute:0];
[nowComponents setSecond:0];
 
NSDate *thisWeekFriday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
```

Then, you may want to check if `thisWeekFriday` is less than `[NSDate date]`, and get the next Friday if it is. You can move date by one week with:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.week = 1;
NSDate *nextWeekFriday = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:thisWeekFriday options:0];
```

Comment: Today is Tuesday. I set the notification to Monday and it works. Why? How to set the notification only for next Monday's?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the number of days between two dates like this:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                                   fromDate:today
                                                                     toDate:futureDate
                                                                    options:0];
NSInteger daysBetweenDates = dateComponents.day;
```